# How to convert a String into a File Object in java?

Tags: java, groovy

I have file contents in a java string variable, which I want to convert it into a `File` object is that possible?

```
public void setCfgfile(File cfgfile)
{
    this.cfgfile = cfgfile
}

public void setCfgfile(String cfgfile)
{
    println "ok overloaded function"
    this.cfgfile = new File(getStreamFromString(cfgfile))
}
private def getStreamFromString(String str)
{
    // convert String into InputStream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes())
    is
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, could you tell us what you want to achieve? Why a File object? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Ewald: This is a continuation to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639819/how-to-upload-a-file-using-apache-commons-file-upload-from-a-servlet)

Comment: I see - there are two answers below, I won't pollute the post with more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this is Groovy, you can simplify the other two answers with:

```
File writeToFile( String filename, String content ) {
  new File( filename ).with { f ->
    f.withWriter( 'UTF-8' ) { w ->
      w.write( content )
    }
    f
  }
}
```

Which will return a file handle to the file it just wrote `content` into

Comment: @tim_yates: all goes well except when it comes to `XmlSlurper` it gives me `[Fatal Error] E:%5CTomcat%206%5Cbin%5C..%5Cwebapps%5Ccsm%5Cfiles%5C1-105101%5Cac
onsole1_csmagentinhyundai_9.1.xml:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.` the 1st line of the xml is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: I assume it's invalid XML you're writing into the file then?  Have you had a look at it?  Can you read it with XmlSlurper straight from the string before you write it into the file?

Comment: The xml is right as when I pass the xml file directly `FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("C:\\Simon\\csmagentinhyundai_9.1.xml"));` it uploads correctly and also the parser works fine.

Comment: Maybe this is another question?

Comment: ok, i don't want to sound pedantic, but my grooviest version would be:

def f=filename as File
f.withWriter('UTF-8'){it << content}

Comment: Sorry doesn't know, why i am unable to compile your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [apache commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io) lib

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File file, String data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a `File` object from a `String` using the `File(String)` constructor. Note that the File object represents only an abstract path name; not a file on disk.

If you are trying to create an actual file on disk that contains the text held by the string there are several classes that you can use, for example:

```
try {
    Writer f = new FileWriter(nameOfFile);
    f.write(stringToWrite);
    f.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // unable to write file, maybe the disk is full?
    // you should log the exception but printStackTrace is better than nothing
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`FileWriter` will use the platform default encoding when converting the characters of the string to bytes that can be written on disk. If this is a problem you can use a different encoding by wrapping `FileOutputStream` inside an `OutputStreamWriter`. For example:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
Writer f = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(nameOfFile), encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

To write a `String` to a file, you usually should use a [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
private writeToFile(String content) {
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.cfgfile));
        bw.write(content);
     }
    catch(IOException e) {
       // Handle the exception
    }
    finally {   
        if(bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, the `new File(filename)` simply instanciates a new `File` object with the name `filename` (it does not actually create the file on your disk). Therefore, you statement:

```
this.cfgfile = new File(getStreamFromString(cfgfile))
```

will simple instanciate a new `File` with the name the `String` returned by the `this.cfgfile = new File(getStreamFromString` method.